# Dúvida ao chamar função em JavaScript - uso de parenteses

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando um pouco de JavaScript, e me deparei com uma situação que não entendi muito bem. O autor cria uma função e quando vai chamá-la pelo método onclick ele não coloca os parentes da função...

```
        function mostrarAlerta(){
            alert("Hello World!");
        }

        var botao = document.querySelector("button");
        botao.onclick = mostrarAlerta;
```

ou seja, `botao.onclick = mostrarAlerta;` nesse `mostrarAlerta` não deveria vir os parênteses? tipo `botao.onclick = mostrarAlerta()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não. `botao.onclick = mostrarAlerta` atribui a função `mostrarAlerta` à propriedade `onclick`. A própria função é o valor sendo passado.

Se por outro lado você utiliza-se `botao.onclick = mostrarAlerta()`, você estaria invocando a função, e atribuindo o retorno de `mostrarAlerta` à propriedade `onclick`. Ou seja, `onclick` receberia `undefined` (valor retornado por uma função quando você não declara o retorno explicitamente).

Então, você quer atribuir a função `mostrarAlerta` ou `undefined` à `onclick`? Por isso não se utiliza parenteses nesse exemplo.

Comment: Entendi! muito obrigado!